# Python Vigenere tuple error

Tags: python, vigenere

I'm trying to make a Vigenere cipher. When I try to encrypt the message I get the following error.

```
    cipherCharIndexValue = baseAlphabet.index(keyList[keyIncrement]) + baseAlphabet.index(plainTextChar)
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

I'm not sure what is wrong is causing the error any help?

```
baseAlphabet = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 
'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')

plainText = input("Please enter the plain text")
key = input("Please enter the key word")
keyList = []
keyLength = 0
while keyLength < len(plainText):
    #Adds the users entered key into a list character by character. 
    #Also makes the key the same length as plainText
    for char in key:
        if keyLength < len(plainText):
            keyList.append(str(char))
            keyLength = keyLength + 1

#The variable each processed letter is appended to
completeCipherText = [] 
#This is the value used to temporaily store the ciphertext character during the iteration
cipherCharIndexValue = 0
keyIncrement = 0

#iterates through the plain text
for plainTextChar in plainText:
        #Adds the base alphabets index value of the key and the plain text char
        cipherCharIndexValue = baseAlphabet.index(keyList[keyIncrement]) + baseAlphabet.index(plainTextChar)
        while cipherCharIndexValue > 25:
             #makes the addition value under 26 as to not go out of range of base alphabet tuple
            cipherCharIndexValue = cipherCharIndexValue - 26 
         #appends the ciphertext character to the completeCipherText variable. 
         #The character is the index of the key + index of the       plainTextChar from baseAlphabet
        completeCipherText.append(baseAlphabet[cipherCharIndexValue])
         #Moves onto the next key
        keyIncrement = keyIncrement + 1
print ('').join(completeCipherText)#Makes the result a strings for printing to the console.
```

Comment: I tried running your code and got an IndentationError on line 2. After un-indenting everything up to and including the first while loop, I got an IndentationError on line 28. After un-indenting that line by one space, I got `NameError: name 'baseAlphabet' is not defined`. Please post a [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Either `keyList[keyIncrement]` or `plainTextChar` is not in `baseAlphabet`. You'll need to do some troubleshooting to figure out which value exactly is failing.

Comment: Thank you for editing your code. It runs for me now. When I execute it using Python 2, and enter `"foo"` for the first prompt and `"bar"` for the second prompt, it runs without crashing and outputs `gof`. Please describe what inputs you entered to get your program to crash.

Comment: Consider what happens if `plainText` (or `keyList`) contains a char that isn't in `baseAlphabet`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get that `ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple` error whenever you attempt to get the index of a char that's not in `baseAlphabet`. So you need to make sure that `key` only contain such chars, and when encoding `plainText` either avoid encoding "bad" chars and just copy them to the `completeCipherText` list unchanged, or convert them to a valid `baseAlphabet` char.

In traditional encryption it was common to convert all spaces and punctuation to another character, eg `'x'` or `'.'`. I decided to add `'.'` to `baseAlphabet` and write a small function `fix_string` to perform that operation. `fix_string` also ensures that all the letters are lower case.

I've also made a few other minor simplifications to your code.

There's no need for `baseAlphabet` to be a tuple. We can use a string. But if you *do* want to use a tuple of single chars there's no need to write it out in full, you can just pass a string to the `tuple` constructor, eg

```
tuple("some string")
```

We generally don't need to keep track of the length of collections like lists, strings, etc. All of the built-in collections track their own length and we can efficiently access that length with the `len()` function.

We don't need `keyIncrement`. Instead, we can loop over the chars of `keyList` and `plainText` in parallel by using the `zip` function.

And instead of using a loop to ensure that the sum of the key and plainText indices are in the proper range we can use the `%` modulus operator.

```
from __future__ import print_function

baseAlphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.'

# Process s so that it only contains chars in baseAlphabet
def fix_string(s):
    # Convert to lower case
    s = s.lower()
    # Convert "other" chars to dot
    a = [ch if ch in baseAlphabet else '.' for ch in s]
    return ''.join(a)

# Vignere cipher
# mode = 1 to encode, -1 to decode
def vignere(plainText, key, mode):
    keyList = []
    while len(keyList) < len(plainText):
        # Adds the key into a list character by character. 
        # Also makes the key the same length as plainText
        for char in key:
            if len(keyList) < len(plainText):
                keyList.append(str(char))

    # The variable each processed letter is appended to
    completeCipherText = []

    # iterates through the plain text
    for keyChar, plainTextChar in zip(keyList, plainText):
        # Adds the base alphabet's index value of the plain text char and the key char
        cipherCharIndexValue = baseAlphabet.index(plainTextChar) 
        cipherCharIndexValue += mode * baseAlphabet.index(keyChar)
        # makes the addition value in range(len(baseAlphabet))
        cipherCharIndexValue = cipherCharIndexValue % len(baseAlphabet)

        # appends the ciphertext character to the completeCipherText variable. 
        # The character is the index of the key + index of the plainTextChar from baseAlphabet
        completeCipherText.append(baseAlphabet[cipherCharIndexValue])

    # Makes the result a string
    return ''.join(completeCipherText)

# Test

# plainText = raw_input("Please enter the plain text")
# key = raw_input("Please enter the key word")

plainText = 'This, is a test string!'
key = 'the key'

# Process plainText and key so that they only contain chars in baseAlphabet
plainText = fix_string(plainText)
key = fix_string(key)

ciphertext = vignere(plainText, key, 1)
print(ciphertext)

decoded = vignere(ciphertext, key, -1)
print(decoded)
```

**output**

```
lomrjdfkgezciplgwsamkzg
this..is.a.test.string.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using python2.x,you should use `raw_input` rather than `input`.

If there're blanks or other punctuation in your input string,your code will crash,so I suggest you make sure that `keyList[keyIncrement]` is in `baseAlphabet` before you use `index` method,if it's not in this tuple,you will get this error:

```
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

e.g.

```
if keyList[keyIncrement] in keyList:
    cipherCharIndexValue = baseAlphabet.index(keyList[keyIncrement]) + baseAlphabet.index(plainTextChar)
```

Or you can use `try/catch` to catch the exception in order to debug your code.

Hope this helps.